# Items bought for staff to work remotely, kept by staff

Tags: united-states, accounting, non-profit

I volunteer for a small US-registered non-profit (almost all activities are conducted outside the US, but I'm asking about US accounting).  We're trying to record some expenses and are unsure what we should record them as.

The NP had some paid staff in another country.  Each of them was provided with a (cheap) laptop to work on, and one was also provided a small power generator.  The intent was that these staff would all be long term, and that the equipment basically belonged to the non-profit so the staff could do their work.

Unfortunately covid had a negative impact on finances and all the staff in that country had to be let go.  They were told they could keep the equipment (simply because that was the simplest way to deal with it, rather than getting one of the now laid-off staff to send it all back to the US or sell it on behalf of the NP).

So the equipment was initially bought as office equipment - but we're not sure how to record it now.  If it matters, this was all in the same financial year.

What should we record these as?  Office equipment still?  Or some kind of Employee benefit?  Something else?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for the **Personal** Finance & Money stack.  Having said that... I'd probably just write off the equipment.

Comment: Thank you @RonJohn - I hadn't even registered the "Personal" part!